# Zing chart load webapi Json data Issue

Tags: zingchart

Am trying to load Zingchart using JSON data retrieved from Webapi.

The sample data is like this

```
$scope.testValues = [{"text":"Sample1","values":"[465]"},{"text":"Sample2","values":"[288]"}];
```

But ZingChart is expecting the values to be..

```
[{"text":"Sample1","values":[465]},{"text":"Sample2","values":[288]}];
```

(Without quotes in the values*)

and because of this am getting a different output in UI as the chart is showing 2 or 3 times

[image]

Can you please let me know how to bind a JSON data from webapi to chart dynamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the quotes before and after the brackets[] using:

```
    var eventlist = JSON.stringify(testValues);
    var eventstring = new String();
    eventstring = eventlist.replace(/"\[/g, '[');
    eventstring = eventstring.replace(/\]"/g, ']');
```

So your final code is:

```js
  var testValues = [{"text":"Sample1","values":"[465]"},{"text":"Sample2","values":"[288]"}];
  var eventlist = JSON.stringify(testValues);
  var eventstring = new String();
  eventstring = eventlist.replace(/"\[/g, '[');
  eventstring = eventstring.replace(/\]"/g, ']');
    
var myConfig = {
  type: 'pie', 
 series: JSON.parse(eventstring)
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
.zc-ref {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com">Powered by ZingChart</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Akash,

The eventString now changed to string data type instead of string array and now also getting different ouput

The chart is showing as "Series1", "Series2"..."Series75" in 5 columns

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a matter of of how you data is formatted. You can see the `values` array is string quoted like `"[458]"` which I assume is coming from php?

It doesn't really matter where its coming from, this is not a valid type for an array. Its a string with brackets inside so of course its showing up as NAN.

There are probably better ways to approach a solution, but this will work

1) Test it out: 
`console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.testValues)))`

2) `$scope.testValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.testValues))`

Comment: while writing to console.log, am getting the desired output, but when I pass this to chart Series,
series:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.testValues))
getting the same issue, showing 3-4 charts